# How to extract only alphanumeric values in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

```
Data
ABC123
JKL685
UJKLPN
655789
```

Output:
ABC123 and JKL685 should show true and the remainder are false. How to achieve this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my suggestion using Power Query:

```
let
    numbers = List.Transform(List.Numbers(0,10), each Text.From(_) ),
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WcnRyNjQyVorViVby8vYxszAFM0OB7AA/MNPM1NTcwlIpNhYA", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Data = _t]),
    #"Filtered numerical" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each try if Value.Type(Number.From([Data])) = type number then false else true otherwise true),
    #"Filtered alphabetical" = Table.SelectRows(#"Filtered numerical" ,
        (FindStrings) => 

    List.AnyTrue(List.Transform(numbers, each Text.Contains((FindStrings[Data]),_ ))))
    
    
in
    #"Filtered alphabetical"
```

It first filters away the fully numerical entries by attempting to convert to number and keeping only rows that cannot be converted. It then filters rows that only contain letters. It's probably not extremely efficient, but works with the sample data.